# CSS hover on container

Tags: html, css

So I'm generally very savvy when it comes to CSS but I have something that's stumping me a bit. The goal here is that a collection of elements inside a container all have the same hover effect at the same time. Here is the code so far: 
HTML:

```
<a href="" class="link-block no-decoration">
   <h6 class="uppercase">whitepaper</h6>
   <div class="section-break section-break-sm">
      <h4>Cras Fusce Fermentum Tortor Porta 4</h4>
      <span class="icon-file icon-2x">​</span>
   </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link-block *:hover {
    color: #0eb2ff !important;
    border-top-color: #0eb2ff;
}
```

So the important class here is link-block, and the goal, as stated above, is to simply force ALL elements inside that class to use these hover attributes.

Here is what's needed: 
[image]

But here is what's happening:

[image]

Thanks for any sound advice!

Comment: did you try `.link-block:hover * {...}` ?

Comment: I did, as well as the two suggestions below. It seems the best I can get out of this is the text elements only change color when they are specifically hovered on, not when the container is hovered on, which is not the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

The `a` is an inline element so you need to set it to display:block and then you can simply apply the :hover state to it directly.

```css
.link-block {
  display:block
}
  
  .link-block:hover {
    color: #0eb2ff !important;
    border-top-color: #0eb2ff;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="link-block no-decoration">
   <h6 class="uppercase">whitepaper</h6>
   <div class="section-break section-break-sm">
      <h4>Cras Fusce Fermentum Tortor Porta 4</h4>
      <span class="icon-file icon-2x">​</span>
   </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Great suggestion, I hadn't thought of this. Gave it an upvote because it's sound logic, sadly no green check though as it did not solve the issue entirely (the icon and border now highlight on hover; the text elements, however, only highlight when you specifically hover over them and not when you just hover over the container.

I've since noticed some global stuff at play, so looks like I might be dealing with specificity issues. If that's the case, I'll come back bearing a green check for ya ;).

Answer (score 3):

Just change the

```
.link-block *:hover {
```

to

```
.link-block:hover {
```

Comment: Upvoted because this is a smart suggestion, unfortunately it's one I had already tried and does not fix the issue.